# If I move from one state to another for graduate school, then should I fill out my moving expenses on next year's IRS form?

Tags: tax-deduction, irs, moving

Here is the [IRS form](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040.pdf).

And if I fill out my moving expenses, then what counts as moving expenses, and what doesn't count? Does buying boxes for moving count as a moving expense? Also, should I keep all of my receipts and include it on next year's IRS form?

Comment: -1  If you will just read the last page of Form 3903, it says "Use Form 3903 to figure your moving expense deduction for a move related to the start of work at a new principal place of  work (workplace)."  It would be hard to justify graduate study on a fellowship (as you have stated elsewhere in regard to another question) as a principal place of work.  Yes, you will have to work hard in graduate school, but I doubt the IRS will accept that as work in the sense it uses the word.

Comment: What if it's a TAship or a RAship though? The fellowship only lasts for 1 year, after which I'm on TAship/RAship.

Comment: From _where_ will you be moving in the year in which your employment begins? Unless you have a contract in place offering you employment sometime in 2013 and can persuade the IRS that you are moving to Providence RI (possibly) in August 2012 to await the start of your employment the following year, I don't think it is going to work. As mhoran_psprep points out, there are time and distance requirements that have to be met, and moving from one apartment in Providence RI to another is not going to count.  Save your packing boxes for re-use. If not, please recycle instead of throwing them out.

Comment: Okay - good points there. I'm moving from Seattle to Providence (probably) in July/August. The other interesting twist to this (though I doubt it will change things) is that most students are given TAships/RAships. But it's okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You attached a link to the 1040 form, which told you you needed [IRS form 3903](http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f3903.pdf). It discusses the time and distance tests and discusses what can be claimed.

> Moves within or to the United States or its possessions. Enter
>   the amount you paid to pack, crate, and move your household
>   goods and personal effects. You can also include the amount you
>   paid to store and insure household goods and personal effects
>   within any period of 30 days in a row after the items were moved
>   from your old home and before they were delivered to your new
>   home.

Yes keep your receipts. They will be needed in case you are audited. Unless the forms tells you to attach them, there is no need to send the receipts to the IRS.

Make sure that you will meet the time and distance requirements.

Comment: One thing to read carefully about is whether going to graduate school counts as employment for the purpose of deducting moving expenses.  If you are getting a job there (possibly as a research or teaching assistant), that's a job; fellowships or going to school on your own money are not jobs.

Comment: Hmm good point. I'm on fellowship for 1st year, then on TAship/RAship so it makes the situation more tricky..